# screen goes white before splash in android

Tags: android

I have tried with below code it is not working in design support

```
<activity
    android:name="first Activity Name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android studio 2.0 or above version it is happening because of instant run. by removing it from settings>Bulid, Execution, Deployment> Instant run and disable all the check boxes over there here is snapshot for the settings screen

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code in you styles.xml

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Comment: '<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    </style>'  this is my current theme