# My main Activity gets a white screen on launch

Tags: java, android, xml

I have created an app in which the main Activity gets a white screen.
I am not getting it...
Whenever I launch my app it's only showing a white screen and nothing else.

I am so confused, please help

here is my code

main activity

```
package com.example.admin.pcremote;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
ListView list;
String[] menutitles;
String[] menudescriptions;
int images[]={R.drawable.mouse,R.drawable.keyboard,R.drawable.filemanager,R.drawable.media,R.drawable.power};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    Resources res = getResources();
    menutitles=res.getStringArray(R.array.titles);
    menudescriptions=res.getStringArray(R.array.descriptions);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listadapter adptr=new listadapter(this,menutitles,images,menudescriptions);
    list.setAdapter(adptr);
    onclick();
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Setting", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }else if (id == R.id.exit) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setMessage("Do You Want To Exit?").setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.setTitle("Exit!!");
            alert.show();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
 }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" >

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: One must proof-read one's titles...

Comment: Please add listadapter code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [screen goes white before splash in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36966080/screen-goes-white-before-splash-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have also got the same problem try this. it worked for me.

**Changed** in **content_main.xml** in **desing** view From **AppTheme.NoActionBar** to **AppTheme**

[image: in design view]

[image]

Comment: i am not getting it where to do it :(

Comment: you will get in double click on file and in bottom side you will get design view and text view

Comment: This is an real answer just check it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36966080/screen-goes-white-before-splash-in-android

Comment: @PatelPinkal above solution worked for me that why i posted

Comment: @NileshIndalkar you are right but I want to know you about real problem, its may help you further, that's my main reason

Comment: i have also tried to disable the instant run bt no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include your content page here!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">
```

> ```
>     <!--Main Content Goes Here-->
> <include layout="@layout/content_home_page" />
> ```

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" >

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: do you have the include of contents in the activity_main layout ? if not do that like i mentioned