# Splashscreen for Android app with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, firebase-realtime-database, splash-screen

My app includes a lot of Firebase Libraries and when the app first starts it can take a while until the app is shown. On older smartphones, it can take up to a few seconds, where you can only see a white screen. On newer phones, it's not that long, but still noticeable.

I am not sure that this is caused by Firebase but I have another Firebase project that doesn't include any other libraries and it is just as slow. And I also read that other people complained about this.

I wanted to know if it is possible to show a loading screen to make my appear more smooth. I already tried to turn off "Instant Run" but that didn't change it.

The first activity that is loaded has no initial Firebase Listeners that retrieve loads of data, I only send a request to my Firebase Functions via the database to retrieve the users feed.

Here are the Gradle dependencies I use:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:1.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.+'
compile 'com.flurgle:camerakit:0.9.17'
compile 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:2.0.2'
compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:+'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.2.6'
```

Comment: Refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36966080/screen-goes-white-before-splash-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/) is cool guide for making splash screen in Android. You pretty much create empty activity with `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` Theme and some image as background

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. Do you know how to scale the bitmap in the layer list for API levels below 23?

Comment: you can use `android:gravity="fill"` or something like this, it should work in Layer lists

Answer (score 0):

> One is showing splash screen using a timer and second is showing splash screen when making network http calls which takes some time to fetch required information.

**Try to use this way**

[Better Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486789/how-do-i-make-a-splash-screen)