# slow startup (500ms) with all apps made by My Android studio

Tags: android, delay, startup

I'm a beginner and when i ever i make an app and i test it on real phone

the first activity takes 400-900ms to start, even when it's only show a text view or a button. (just empty App)

on the same phone i have few apps (Games) from Play Store , and they work instantly! there's no 10ms delay!

so I'm wondering why is this happening to me even if i make (Empty App)

I mean seriously, why would it starts slowly with this simple code:

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setText("Hello World");

   }
 }
```

Comment: is your instant run enabled ? i have seen it takes time to load the app if its enabled.

Comment: `test it on real phone` are you generating the apk ? signing it without debug option? or just launching it ?

Comment: i made it with and without instant run feature, and i can't see a different

Comment: Build->Build APK and i take the apk file to my phone and install it.

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36966080/screen-goes-white-before-splash-in-android

Comment: If instant run is enabled, disable it and try launching application

Comment: it's not enabled, and my app doesn't starts instantly for some reason

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the APK you are generating is with debug property on, so this APK is considered to be in development mode that's why it will take longer to launch. You need to generate a production APK (same one you can publish on Play Store) in order to have the same launch speed as the other apps. Check this out : [Sign Your APK](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#sign-apk)

Comment: oh let me try that now

Comment: Yamen , i just did this , i generated a signed apk (release) but i can't install on my phone , i get this error : app is not installed

Comment: Then this is a different error, even with signed APK connect to your android studio you should see an error in the logcat. but as i said its a different issue. check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226132/app-not-installed-error-on-android

Comment: ok i fixed that by uninstalling the previous version from my phone, but i still see delay ! same thing

Comment: first thing shows up is a white window then after 500ms app starts.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not enabled and still show some delay start